# Querying distinct with MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

How do I query **distinct** with MongoMapper? My query is:

`subscribedToThread = Comment.where(:subscribe_thread => 1).all`

But this will return many objects with the same `user_id`. I need to return just a distinct `user_id`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you will need to drop down to the ruby driver in order to do this as I don't think you can do this with MongoMapper itself:

```
subscribedToThread = Comment.collection.distinct("user_id", {:subscribe_thread => 1})
```

Calling the collection method on a model returns the collection as would be provided by the Ruby driver directly so you can issue a distinct query using the syntax below:

`collection.distinct(key, query = nil)`

You can read more about it [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do so:

```
subscribedToThread = Comment.where(:subscribe_thread => 1).fields(:user_id).all.compact!.unique!
```

This will nil every field but user_id which you then `uniq!`,ie you remove all doubles and then `compact!` all nil

http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html#fields

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
subscribedToThread = Comment.where(:subscribe_thread => 1).fields(:user_id).collect(&:user_id).uniq
```

It will show you list of uniq user_id

Comment: This performs the distinction operation on the ruby side, after fetching all the authors of the comments. So it won't be efficient for collections having a lot of objects with not unique values (in this case a big collection of comments created by several users).

Answer (score 0):

For the original post, try this:

```
subscribedToThread = Comment.where(:subscribe_thread => 1).distinct(:user_id)
```

I wanted to count the number of distinct entries when the user chose type = "Other" from the list and entered a custom name (so that I could consider adding more common choices to the list).

```
InteriorInfo.where(type: 'Other').distinct(:name).sort.each{|i| puts "%3d %s" % [InteriorInfo.where(name: i).count, i]}
```

Resulting in (snippet)

```
  6 AED
  1 Alarm Panel
 16 Basement Access
```