# Get distinct users in a list using mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm creating an application where users can make check-ins in some places, so a place may contains many checkins and a user can check-in as often as he wants

Having a place and the list of check-ins i can see the users but if a user checked-in more than once the list of users will contain duplicated users.

How i can get a distinct list of users who checked-in in a specific place, i'm using mongomapper

Comment: I saw this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098605/querying-distinct-with-mongomapper, but i think i need something like Place.find('someid').checkins.distinct(:user)

Comment: my option now is create a method that filter a list of users returning another list with distinct users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If checkins are embedded, you're going to have to do your "distinct" filtering with Ruby's `uniq`.

If your checkins are simple Mongo documents like the following:

```
{
  _id:      ObjectId("123abc"),
  place_id: ObjectId("123abc"),
  user_id:  ObjectId("123abc")
}
```

...then you can do `CheckIns.where(:place_id => my_place.id).distinct(:user_id)`. Then map those to users.

From the very little information you've given about your schema, it sounds like your data is strongly relational. You *may* be better off with a relational database.

Comment: yes, checkin is a mongo document the method you showed worked for me. Mongomapper api gives me methods to make associations, there are any downside using relations in a non relational database? In this specific case i don't care to relational integrity.

Comment: To get the full benefits of relationships in Mongo, you need to avoid embedding, and that *can* be a performance hit (no joins).  If you're not performance-constrained (most of the time you won't be) or you don't need database-enforced relational integrity, then you're fine.

Outside of performance, the biggest thing you get w/ActiveRecord over MongoMapper is has_many :through (i.e. "join tables"). Join tables are really nice to have when you need to store information about a *relationship*. You can do it in MongoMapper manually, but you just don't get as much syntactic sugar to do it.